# Iptables masquerade breaks dns lookups

Tags: linux, iptables, dns

I'm testing something with IP masquerade on locally generated traffic but it seems to be breaking DNS lookups. Everything else works fine--all IP traffic without DNS queries work.

```
$ iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j MARK --set-mark 2
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 0x2 -j MASQUERADE
```

Why does this work with all IP traffic except DNS queries?

Results of requested commands below:

```
# ip address

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 54:21:c6:28:99:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c1:b2:a1:55:34:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.108/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 242078sec preferred_lft 242078sec
    inet6 fe80::1dd6:f094:be8d:ef51/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

```
# ip route

default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.108 metric 600
```

---

In a surprise twist, systemd is acting as a DNS server on 127.0.0.53.

---

`systemctl status systemd-resolved` is reporting "systemd-resolved[3315]: Got packet on unexpected IP range, refusing." after enabling the two commands.

---

I believe this issue may be related.

- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66067
- https://github.com/kontena/pharos-cluster/issues/482

The relevant portions of those two links are:

> all queries to 127.0.0.53:53 goes not from 127.0.0.0/8, but from interface with default route due to masquerading, and systemd-resolved rejects all of these requests with
>
> systemd-resolved[21366]: Got packet on unexpected IP range, refusing.

`systemd-resolved` goes to the extra effort of validating the stub resolver source/dest addresses, and thus MASQUERADE rule breaks those assumptions:

```
if (in_addr_is_localhost(p->family, &p->sender) <= 0 ||
            in_addr_is_localhost(p->family, &p->destination) <= 0) {
                log_error("Got packet on unexpected IP range, refusing.");
                dns_stub_send_failure(m, s, p, DNS_RCODE_SERVFAIL, false);
                goto fail;
        }
```

Comment: Unless you bring much more detail and debugging data on this question, it is too vague as it is. We won´t be able to guess up the details that are missing here.

Comment: Try it on your own box.  You will see.  Then delete the rules.   You will be able to ping out.  You will be able to visit any site in a browser via just the ip address.  You will not be able to ping dns names or visit sites with a browser via name.  It can't get any more clear than this if you try it.  It's exceedingly easy to try as well.  Delete the rules with: iptables -t mangle -D OUTPUT -j MARK --set-mark 2;

iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 0x2 -j MASQUERADE

Comment: Perhaps it will help to see the packet flow.  Essentially this marks all locally generated traffic then changes the source address to what it should have been anyhow.  At least that's my understanding.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg

Comment: Bill. I tried i just can' t emulate, maybe because you have more than this two rules? Please explain. Is this a router? Is the tests of DNS being doing inside the router or in machines using this as a router? Where in your network this machine is, what do you expect to occur with this two rules. You marked the packet right! Will this affect routing tables?

Comment: It's a generic build of Ubuntu 18.04, either desktop or server.  It's not a router.  Ip forwarding is NOT enabled.  https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux  Thanks for trying it.  Uninstall UFW after the generic build.  Basically a generic linux build with no iptables rules to start with.  I am testing with wireless and on the desktop version with dhcp.   Maybe I"m wrong but I don't think that should matter.

Comment: iptables -nvL -t nat; iptables -nvL -t mangle; iptables -nvL -t filter; iptables -nvL -t raw    //all show nothing when you start--no rules.

Comment: So let me see if i understand you have a desktop machine and add this rules, and dns just stop im right? You don't have any route rules, like route tables and others?

Comment: This is correct Luciano.  If you do this and try to ping 8.8.8.8 it will work fine.  If you try to ping google.com it will never resolve but if you supply google.com's ip address it does work--as a simple example.  I'm trying to understand why this is breaking dns queries as all source ip addresses should just be changed to what they would have been anyhow.  I'd like to see a fix for it other than removing the rules.  :)

Comment: Right i do the two commands, and ping 8.8.8.8 is working and also www.gooogle.com is resolving including with nslookup... Maybe you have a strange interface or route configuration can you post the outputs of ip address and ip route on  your question? And if you have a route table the results of it. Thanks. I added a ip route table 2  with fwmark 2 using this and seems to still work ok

Comment: If a local DNS server is listening on `any` or eg 127.0.1.1 and superseding the dhcp's dns setting in /etc/resolv.conf, then doing a query to 127.0.1.1 (anything else than 127.0.0.1) can go wrong, eg (`conntrack -E`): `[NEW] udp 17 30 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.1.1 sport=38781 dport=53 [UNREPLIED] src=127.0.1.1 dst=10.0.3.66 sport=53 dport=38781`. Answer fails (EINVAL) if answering with sendto(). I have some theories, but first there are a lot of **if**s that OP should confirm. doesn't involve mark. btw avoiding it is simple: state the interface in iptables to filter out `lo`.

Comment: I shouldn't have a dns server running locally, as far as I know.  A. B. anything you want me to try I'll give it a go.  If you can, be specific with your commands.  Sounds like you know this a lot better than me.  Thanks!  resolv.conf seems to be managed by systemd  # 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53

Comment: So you do have a local dns server (anyway, a query done on 127.x.x.x-which-isn't-127.0.0.1)... ok. i'll do an answer but sorry that won't be before the next day (anybody else feel free to do so). I'm not sure it will give a real root cause, but at least how to reproduce, what is happening and how to avoid. Meanwhile you should [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/466105/edit) your question and add the piece of information from your comment

Comment: Wait, you're saying systemd is acting as a dns server here?  I didn't install that.  Is this something new with Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: I'll be darned if systemd isn't acting a some kind of dns server on 127.0.0.53.

Comment: Ok, A.B. you genius...systemctl status systemd-resolved is reporting "systemd-resolved[3315]: Got packet on unexpected IP range, refusing." after enabling the two commands.  This seems to be the issue.

Comment: Thanks A.B and  Luciano Andress Martini for helping me arrive at a solution!  I tried to thank you guys in the post but it seems to have been deleted out.

Comment: while in the end it's related to doing NAT between 127.0.0.0/8 and non-127.0.0.0/8 , after many tests, this shouldn't have prevented it to work (my comment about sendto() was wrong). As your log tells, it's indeed the application which ignored the source IP (not 127.0.0.1 anymore, but probably something like 192.168.x.x) or refused to send an answer to it, for security reason, and not a problem in the strange nat/routing, so not worth an additional answer

Answer (score 6):

This worked fine to me. Just exclude the local interface and nslookup works fine.

```
sudo iptables ! -o lo -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me based on systemd-resolved behavior was to implement the rules like this:

```
$ iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT ! -s 127.0.0.1 -j MARK --set-mark 2
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 0x2 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 0):

I turned off systemd-resolved, but still have a dns resolver problem which I fix by using your mangle solution.

Posing an alt Answer, because maybe we just want iptables and not systemd-resolved to be our firewall:

StubListener to no in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/00-`hostname`.conf

For an uncomfortable while, we just had systemd-resolved and no way to stop it from running and taking firewall domain away from iptables.

For a while we have had an option to stop that, and either go back to just deferring to google resolver, or opennic resolvers. Check namebench, for picking locally fastest.

Or, we can have dnsmasq, or good old djbdns dnscache. We can improve on google and/or opennic or whatever, either by dnsmasq or dnscache or a combination. I am using dnsmasq with namebench-ed opennic plus 127.0.0.53 dnscache, so www.bigtube.com SERVFAIL is not taking three minutes! I have dnsmasq 127.0.0.1 in /etc/resolvconf and NetworkManager. Erwin Hoffmann's djbns dnscache does have ipv6, not that I care personally.